# What is a projection in set theory?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I've been told that a projection is a function that maps a set of ordered pairs to either the set of all first coordinates, or the set of all second coordinates. So if $f: X\times Y \to X$ or $f: X\times Y \to Y$ , then *f* is a projection. But what about for functions of several variables? If *f* is a function defined by $f: (x,y,z) \to x$, is *f* still a projection? Could anyone direct me to a general definition of "projection" in set theory? Also could you try being as elementary as possible, I'm still getting used to notations and concepts. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Yes, it's still a projection. There's a wikipedia article about projections in set theory: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_(set_theory).

Comment: I would say a projection is any idempotent map.   That is to say, a projection on $X$ is a map $f:X\to X$ such that $f\circ f=f$.  I would not call your examples projections unless you have previously identified $X,Y$ as subsets of $X\times Y$.

Comment: No, just knowing $f:X\times Y\to X$ does not make $f$ a projection!

Comment: @lulu In the (category theoretical) definition of the product, I would find it very strange to _not_ call these maps projections, even though they aren't endomorphisms.

Comment: @Arthur  To me, the idempotency is critical.  With the OP's examples, $f\circ f$ is undefined.

Comment: @lulu So do you have a good alternative name for the canonical maps $X\times Y\to X$ and $X\times Y\to Y$ in the definition of products? ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_(category_theory)) calls them projections.) What about bundles? Do they not have projection maps? ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bundle_(mathematics)#Definition) seems to think they do.) (Yes, I know Wikipedia isn't an authority, but it can reasonably be assumed to reflect conventions held by a lot of mathematicians, and I think you will find many other sources with the same naming.)

Comment: @Arthur In that sense, the product is *defined* by the existence of projection morphisms.  That is, the product must include the two canonical projections as part of the definition.  I don't imagine that this is what the OP had in mind.  I expect they were thinking of something like $\mathbb R^2$ with the subsets $\mathbb R\times {0}$ and $0\times \mathbb R$.   But, yes.  If the OP meant to refer to the cartesian product with that extra categorical baggage, then I'd agree.

Comment: @lulu But can orthognal projection of $\Bbb R^2$ onto the $x$-axis not reasonably be thought of as a map $\Bbb R^2\to \Bbb R$ ("remove the second coordinate" rather than "set the second coordinate to $0$") and still deserve the name "projection", even without all that category theoretical baggage?

Comment: @Arthur  Sure, if (as I said initially) you have previously identified that copy of $\mathbb R$ with a subset of the product.  The set theoretic definition would include projections onto other lines.  Not sure how that works categorically...I expect there is an analog.  But for sets I'd call any idempotent map onto a subset a projection.  Don't need to start with a product.

Comment: @lulu The set-theoretic product $X\times Y$ (defined as a set of ordered pairs) doesn't necessarily do that (that requires singling out an element of $X$ and an element of $Y$, such as $0\in \Bbb R$), but I really can't consider that a crucial detail. And you do admit that some times (such as in category theory), projections can be non-endomorphic. Why artificially restrict that freedom to only some contexts?

Comment: @Arthur  But then, absent the notion of a product, how do you define a projection?  I think I would agree that it makes sense to allow both projection onto a factor in a product (the categorical definition) and projection as an idempotent (the set theoretic definition).

Comment: @lulu Okay, so if I have a function from $X \times Y$ to $X$ and also defined by $f:(x,y) \to x$, then is it a projection? As I understood a projection is a function from a set of ordered pairs to the set of all the j-th coordinates in those ordered pairs. Am I wrong?

Comment: @Camelot823  I think Arthur's point is well taken.  The natural projections from a product onto its factors is a projection, even though it lacks the property I want.  In most situations, the issue goes away because we are thinking of the factors as subsets in a natural way.  But, after the discussion, I'd agree that those are projections.

Comment: @lulu Thank you for your insight!

Comment: @lulu "But then, absent the notion of a product, how do you define a projection?" That's a good question. Except here, the entire issue revolves specifically around products. I do agree that idempotent endomorphs deserve to be called projections. But those aren't the only ones that do, and in the context of this post, I think it is wrong to insist on that singular definition.

Comment: @Arthur  I think I agree.  I think there are two (closely related) notions here...the canonical projections attached to a product, and an idempotent map to a subset.  In many cases the distinction doesn't matter and they overlap enough to justify using the same term.

Comment: @lulu That sounds very reasonable.